# Running binary WSGI app

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi, pyinstaller

I have a working wsgi app developed in python. I know that pyinstaller will compile and get me a binary of this application. I have a nginx and uwsgi running. can i use this binary instead of the python script to run the whole thing from uwsgi to boost the speed ..

Answer (score 0):

The binary you get is just your program and a python interperter stuffed together into an executable with all dependencies so that it can be easier distributed. It won't give you any speed boost, and it's not really 'compiled' into a binary.

By using a binary of this kind you would loose all the advantages that WSGI provides you, so it's a bad idea. Just deplay your wsgi application as documented.

Comment: what advantages would I loose? I can't think of any, please give some examples

Comment: You get lots of additional overhead. Each time a instance of the app is started, the embedded interpreter and code has to be unpacked first. A wsgi container keeps it's interpreter instances in memory and can efficiently reuse them, it can't do the same with 'compiled' binaries.